# What function do I use in Sql Server 2005 to get the current datetime in utc?

Tags: sql-server-2005

I've used GetDate() in defaults for a long time.
What is the equivalent call, or logic in SQL 2005 for me to put in a default that will give me the current UTC time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
GETUTCDATE()
```

Answer (score 3):

**GETUTCDATE()**

The difference between GETDATE() and GETUTCDATE() is time zone number of the SQL Server machine.